# How to get second tag in Soup tag object python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a load of tags in a Soup object called `tags` with type <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> in python and want to get the second tag as seen below:

```
<myreports>
<report instance="nvda-20210131.htm">
<isdefault>false</isdefault>
<hasembeddedreports>false</hasembeddedreports>
<htmlfilename>R1.htm</htmlfilename>
<longname>0001001 - Document - Cover Page</longname>
<reporttype>Sheet</reporttype>
<role>http://www.nvidia.com/role/CoverPage</role>
<shortname>Cover Page</shortname>
<menucategory>Cover</menucategory>
<position>1</position>
</report>
```

I know usually in a list or DataFrame etc I can index by using `tags[1]` but this throws an error for Soup objects.

I also cannot do `tags.tag` like I would be able to do `shortname` etc as there is a space in `report instance="nvda-20210131.htm"`.

I want my output to look like this:

```
<report instance="nvda-20210131.htm">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that "load of tags" is a python list? and please show us how the output should look like

Comment: @alexzander I have updated the question but the type is '<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
# to make a list with all of the above tags
children = list(tags.children)

# extract the wanted tag 
wanted_tag = children[1]

# print the tag
print(wanted_tag)
```

you should get this output:

```
<report instance="nvda-20210131.htm">
```

extra [doc](https://linuxhint.com/find_children_nodes_beautiful_soup/) which was my `inspiration`.